# preg_replace with urlencode

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I am trying to create hashtag links with preg_replace and I encounter issues when a "" in the hashtag is present. I am not really good at patterns so any help would be appreciated:

My pattern:

```
$hashtags_url = '/(\#)([x00-\xFF]+[a-zA-Z0-9x00-\xFF_\w]+)/';

$body = preg_replace($hashtags_url, '<a href="'.$hashtag_path.'$2" title="#$2">#$2</a>', $body);
```

This works perfect to a normal hashtag but the issue is when i try to urlencode the $2 parameter.

I tried

```
$hashtags_url = '/(\#)([x00-\xFF]+[a-zA-Z0-9x00-\xFF_\w]+[x00-\xFF]+[a-zA-Z0-9x00-\xFF_\w])/';
```

and

```
   $body = preg_replace_callback(
$hashtags_url,
function($matches) {
    return "<a href=\"$hashtag_path/hashtag/".urlencode($matches[2])."\">#".
           $matches[2]."</a>";
},
$body);
```

and it goes well but now the single-worded hashtags are omitted.

Comment: `$matches[1]` captures `#`, you should use `$matches[2]`. What is the problem with the backslash?

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer! The issue is my regex pattern actually. It takes in consideration only the characters till the backslash and not the ones after. I was using the matches[2] actually. Editing the post now

Comment: What is your `$body` like? And try with `$hashtags_url = '/#(\S+)/';`

Comment: $body example:

$body = "Text text #hashtag text text  #hast/tag";

Comment: See https://3v4l.org/lliBW

Comment: $hashtags_url = '/#(\S+)/'; did the trick. Please post it as an answer and I will select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following simplified regex, with `$matches[1]` to access the hashtag name in the anonymous function used as the replacement argument:

```php
/#(\S+)/
```

Make sure you pass all necessary variables using `use` keyword to the callback function (see `use ($hashtag_path)`).

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/NDTsu):

```php
$body = "Text text #hashtag text text #hast/tag";
$hashtag_path = '/path/to';
$hashtags_url = '/#(\S+)/';
$body = preg_replace_callback(
$hashtags_url, function($matches) use ($hashtag_path) {
    return "<a href=\"$hashtag_path/hashtag/".urlencode($matches[1])."\">".$matches[0]."</a>";
},
$body);
echo $body;
```

Output:

```php
Text text <a href="/path/to/hashtag/hashtag">#hashtag</a> text text <a href="/path/to/hashtag/hast%2Ftag">#hast/tag</a>
```